# Eliminar errores de validacion de formulario con ajax

Tags: php, laravel, ajax

como podria limpiar aquellos campos del formulario que pasan las validaciones? adjunto imagen de mi problema 
[image: formulario]
Lo que sucede es que duplica la validacion al intentar registrar un nuevo cliente; por ejemplo en el campo nombre deberia pasar la validacion sin problemas

Este es mi script: con esto trato de eliminar los errores usado form.find

$('.modal-footer').on('click', '.add', function(e){
      e.preventDefault();

```
  var form = $('#modal-body form');  
  var route = "{{ route('customers.clientes.store') }}";     

  form.find('.help-block').remove();
  form.find('.form-group').removeClass('has-error');


  $.ajax({  
    headers: { 'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content') },      
    url: route,         
    dataType: 'json',
    type: 'POST',   
    data : form.serialize(),
    success: function (response){
      form.trigger('reset');
      $('#modal_agregar').modal('hide');
      $('#clientes-table').DataTable().ajax.reload();

      swal({
          type : 'success',
          title : 'Success!',
          text : 'Data has been saved!'
      });
    },
    error : function(xhr){
      var res = xhr.responseJSON;
      if($.isEmptyObject(res) == false){
         $.each(res.errors, function (key, value){
          $('#' + key)
              .closest('.form-group').find('div:first')
              .addClass('has-error')
              .append('<span class="help-block"><strong>' + value + '</strong></span>');
        });
      } 
    }
  })      
});
```

Espero me puedan orientar gracias!!!